# Esper 8.2 statement stops matching events

Tags: esper

In my application I have about 100 continuous Esper filter queries with events being sent in.  At some point for an unknown reason some of statemens stop matching events and never match any further event without ever throwing an exception (nothing logged in log4j default logging setup).  This is not reproducible in a small example, and I realize that it's difficult to pinpoint a problem like this, but I'm writing this in the hopes of this being a known and/or fixed issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to review your application code to make sure it is still sending events and the listener/subscriber code to make sure it is still processing output events, i.e. exception handling and logging. Or perhaps an OOM occurs and logging doesn't happen and thus you may want to check heap memory use. Also look at console out see if the JVM has encountered an issue.